# "Resulting command line for hg.exe too long" error in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

So, basically about every time I try to do an update to my changed files, I get this awful error. I then have to manually select only some of the files, define a commit message, then come back and select some more files, put other commit text, etc, etc until I have covered all the changed files.

Is there anything simpler, dammit?

I am using Tortoise HG in Visual Studio 2010 ( http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/index_eng.html ), if it makes any difference.

Comment: Which VS addin are you using?

Comment: Have you tried VisualHg instead?

Comment: How many files are you talking about?  What version of TortoiseHg?

Comment: I believe it's tortoise 1.1.61. When I try to commit, they are something like 10-20 files to make changes to.

Comment: I have used VisualHg in the past. I don't remember if the same problem used to happen with that one, though.

Comment: Do you have really deep directory structures?  I've never seen this error.

Comment: I don't think you should get this error from TortoiseHg, since from what I've seen, it seems it talks directly to the Mercurial code, not through a command line, but perhaps the addin in Visual Studio talks to Mercurial through the command line?

Comment: Do you get a more detailed exception message you could paste?

Comment: And are you sure you're actually using TortoiseHg, doesn't that addin implement most of the GUI itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HgSccPackage uses mercurial command line client hg.exe.
There is a limitation on maximum command line length ~2000 characters in the .Net framework API used to run an external process (hg.exe).

And since the commit must be atomic the HgSccPackage fail to complete operation with that error.

You have three options:

1. You have an option to check all changed files in commit window. Then HgSccPackage will call mercurial client to commit all files (without passing each and every one in command line arguments).
2. If it is possible, you can split commit to smaller logical parts with fewer files.
3. If it is possible, revert some files and commit all other at once

It would be much easier if the mercurial client had an option to pass a file list in a file (for example list.txt with file names in each line). But there is no such option.

By the way, the HgSccPackage does not pass a full path for files. Instead it pass the file path relative to the repository root. So, it rather strange, that you hit the command line limit.

How much files you are commiting ?
Why can't you commit all files ?

Comment: @devoured This issue is fixed in HgSccPackage v1.7 (requires mercurial v1.8). Now the files are passed to mercurial with listfile pattern.

Answer (score 1):

[Mercurial SCC Package](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html) checks whether the resulting command line is not greater than 1,700 characters.

I've digged package's source code a bit and apparently when invoking Mercurial's commands it ends up with using `Process.Start()` method on `hg.exe` with `UseShellExecute = false` option specified.

[`Process.Start` method's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) mentions that the sum of the length of the arguments and the length of the full path to the process shouldn't exceed 2080 but digging the .NET Framework itself I was unable to find any enforcement of that limitation. WinAPI [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) function (with which `Process.Start` effectively ends up calling to) have more generous limitation of 32,768 characters.

So it might be bug with VS addin.

As for me when I had a similar problem because my projects was too deep inside `C:\Documents and Settings\Regent\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\` I just created a [NTFS symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and used `C:\Projects\` afterwards.