# Mercurial command line client, reading commands, options, and arguments from a file?

Tags: command-line, mercurial

Is there a way to ask Mercurial to read most/all of the commands, options, and arguments that I want to give it from a response file, instead of passing them on the command line?

For instance, instead of this:

```
hg commit -m "commit message" --INCLUDE file1 --INCLUDE file2 ...
```

I would create a text file containing

```
-m "commit message" --INCLUDE file1 --INCLUDE file2 ...
```

and then ask Mercurial to read it with this (hyphotetical) syntax:

```
hg commit @responses.txt
```

The reason I'm asking is that I'm creating a wrapper library for .NET around the Mercurial command line client, and this question on SO got me worried that the length of the command line might be a problem for me at some point: [“Resulting command line for hg.exe too long” error in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512321/resulting-command-line-for-hg-exe-too-long-error-in-mercurial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this as far as I know, but I think there is a way you can build what you need.

Use the [Mercurial internal API](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi) and write your own wrapper script. Rather than trying to get it to read any and all commands and options, it'll be a lot easier to stick to your specific goal (i.e. "commit" and the options you need).

(Note the warnings on the API page. If this wrapper you're building is going to be distributed to other people, look into the licensing issue and have a plan for how to handle future Mercurial upgrades, which may break your wrapper.)

Comment: That would mean I would have to use the python version of Mercurial. Since I'm writing my own wrapper library, I thought I'd stick with the pure binary version that doesn't require Python to be installed at all, it comes with its own Python libraries bundled.

Comment: I suppose you could hack into that package and add your own wrapper command along the lines of above, but that may be more work than the result is worth to you. And, if the result was deemed a "derived work" it might complicate your distribution plans.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kludgy workaround...

1. Create a dummy, empty response file in the repo's .hg directory, for example .hg\response.
2. In the repo's .hg\hgrc, add the line

   `%include response`
3. Before doing any repository operations, write the command line options to this response file.  Use the `[defaults]` section to (I know it's deprecated) to specify your options.

   `[defaults]`
   `commit = -m "This is a commit message" -I file1 -I file2 ...`

(According to [Microsoft's support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473), the maximum command line is 8,191 characters on XP and later.  Might be useful to know if you even need to use this trick.)

Comment: Since I'm writing a wrapper library for Mercurial, I will refrain from modifying the hgrc file for repositories that aren't mine, and that includes any repositories others might own and use my library against. I've started a lobbying campaign to get proper response files built into Mercurial instead.